# How to implement ssl on everything except a specific and/or a few specific files/folders using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am implementing SSL on everything but would like to exclude a specific page or specific set of pages from using SSL. How can I do this. At the moment I am using the simple syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/myfolder/$1 [R,L]
```

If you could could you explain the steps you are taking in order to do this please so that I can actually understand why and what you have done and I will learn something from this?

Thanks for the help,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(excluded1|excluded2)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/myfolder/$1 [R,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !` is for excluding listed paths in https redirection.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, so ! is except and the pipes are used to divide the folders and files in case I have more than one. Why are there two slashed on either side of the parentheses and the NC? thanks

Comment: Actually I have just tried this out and it doesn't seem to work. I have an html file and this is what I have done: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(page1.html)/ [NC]. Is there something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Actually I have just solved it. I got rid of the parentheses and the two slashes. Thanks for the help! John